# Возвращаемое значение prompt();

Tags: javascript, методы, prompt

какое значение возвращает "пустой" метод prompt(); Если просто нажать кнопку "ОК"?

Comment: А проверить? Или прочитать документацию?

Answer (score 0):

`prompt` всегда возвращает `string`, независимость от того что вы написали в поле,
если вы просто нажали `OK` нечего не написав он вернёт пустой `string`, если написали номер, например `123` то он вернёт `string` с значение `123`

```js
let test = prompt('Значение');

console.log(typeof test, test);
```

Comment: Если ввели цифру, то оно ее возвращает в виде строки, а как тогда сделать проверку на тип данных 'number'?

Comment: @Vlodek никак. можно только кастануть и проверить что там реально число, например через parseInt  или `Number(ТУТ СТРОКА)` (в принципе оно и проверяет)